# implementação do Split() em C++

Tags: c#, c++, string, split

Estava procurando uma forma de implementar a função .split() do C# em C++ e encontrei o seguinte código no google:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& text, char sep)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;

    while ((end = text.find(sep, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        tokens.push_back(text.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + 1;
    }

    tokens.push_back(text.substr(start));
    return tokens;
}
```

Coloquei o código no meu projetinho, testei e vi que funcionava, então parti logo pra tentar entender exatamente como o algoritmo funciona.
Entendi a maior parte do código, mas travei na parte da condição do while:

```
while ((end = text.find(sep, start)) != std::string::npos)
```

Eu meio que compreendi que ele verifica se ainda há o valor do **char sep** (uma ',' por ex.) na string, mas não consegui entender **como** ele faz isso.
Alguém poderia me explicar detalhadamente como esse trecho do código funciona?
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `find` procura a posição do caractere `sep` começando a partir do índice `start`, se ele achar ele retorna a posição do caractere para `end`, senão retorna `npos` para `end`.

Por isso que a condição do `while` é que ele continue iterando enquanto `end` seja diferente de `npos`.

O método `substr` copia uma determinada quantidade de caracteres de uma string começando por um índice que seria `start` e a quantidade seria `end - start`.

Simplificando seria isso:

```cpp
std::string text { "texto1,texto2,texto3" };

size_t start = 0, end = 0;

end = text.find(',', start); // start(0), end(6) != npos (true, executa o while)

{
  text.substr(start, end - start); // 0, (6 - 0 = 0) = texto1

  start = end + 1; // 6 + 1 = 7
}

end = text.find(',', start); // start(7), end(13) != npos (true, executa o while)

{
  text.substr(start, end - start); // 7, (13 - 7 = 6) = texto2

  start = end + 1; // 13 + 1 = 14
}

end = text.find(',', start); // start(14), end(npos) != npos (false, encerra o while)

text.substr(start); // copia do índice 14 até o final, que seria o texto3
```

Links para a documentação das funções:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi; se o .find() não encontrar o caractere (end = text.find(sep, start)), ele retorna npos para o end e em seguida avalia se o end é diferente de npos, certo? (end != std::string::npos)

Comment: @Pedro sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: muito obrigado, cara. entendi perfeitamente agora!

Answer (score 2):

Existe algo mais simples do que isso:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector <string> split(string text, char separator = ' '){
    string str;
    stringstream ss(text);
    vector <string> result;
    while(getline(str, ss, separator)){
        result.pushback(str);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Eu sei que não quer ver isso, mas tem como reverter:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string unsplit(vector<string> setence, char spliter = ' '){
    string result;
    for(int i = 0; i < setence.size; i++){
        result = result + setence[i] + spliter;
    }
    result.remove(result.size - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escrevi um split() como se fosse um algoritmo da stl em C++ Moderno :

```
template<typename it, typename valueT, typename outIt>
void split(it first, it last, const valueT& e, outIt&& o) {
    auto next = first;
    while ( next != last ) {
        next = std::find(first, last, e);
        *o++ = { first, next };
        first = next;
        first++;
    }
}
```

1 - Funciona com iteradores, begin(), end(), istream_iterator...

```
string x = ",teste,oi,vamos";
split(x.begin(), x.end(), ',', ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

2 - Funciona com sequencias vazias;

```
 string x = ",teste,oi,vamos";
 string y = ",,,,";
 string z = "";
```

3 - Funciona com qualquer container, não só strings;

```
 vector v = {30, 20, 0, 40, 50, 10, 70, 0, 20, 30};
 vector<vector<int>> splitted;
 cout << "Separando um vetor com em vários vetores " << endl;  
 split(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, back_inserter(splitted));
```

4 - Tem versão com lambda;

```
split_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto const& val) { return val < 20; }, back_inserter(w));
```

5 - Não faz cópia de valores ( salvo o caso de o iterador copiar );

```
vector<string_view> w;  // <-  string view não copia
split(x.begin(), x.end(), ',', back_inserter(w));
```

exemplo funcional https://godbolt.org/z/x76ojc